# Show data as checkboxes from 2 related tables

Tags: php

I have related data in 2 tables in the database. Let's say table A and table B. Table A data is shown in the form as check boxes. And those check boxes only should be checked if those values are in Table 2. I hope you got the point. For clarification please find the attached images. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
<?php

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Table 1

$b = array(2, 3); // Table 2

for ($x = 0; $x < count($a); $x++) {
    for ($y = $x; $y < count($b); $y++) {
        if ($a[$x] == $a[$x]) {
           echo '<input type="checkbox" name="att'.$x.'" selected="selected" />';
        } else {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="att'.$x.'" />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[Link to image 1](http://www.nuwanblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/check_boxes.jpg)

[Link to image 2](http://www.nuwanblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/screen1.png)

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Comment: No one in their right mind is going to sit and write all of this code for you.... without requiring payment. Make an attempt, at the very least, post your code and THEN, maybe, you'll get some help getting it fixed up.

Comment: Sorry! I just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array(2, 3); 

foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {  
      if ($a[$key] == in_array($value,$b)) {                
         echo $value.' <input type="checkbox" name="att'.$value.'" checked="checked" /><br />';
      } else {
         echo $value.' <input type="checkbox" name="att"'.$value.'" /><br />';
      }    
}
```